# Is there a way to write a message in kafka with some timeout per message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am new to kafka and I know that we can give e.g. delete.retention.ms on topic creation, and all messages that match to this criterion will be deleted.
I would like to know whether there's a way to give this criterion per message? Or maybe there's any hack to achieve the goal?

Comment: did you look at this `Request.timeout.ms`? in apache producer config

Comment: @Deadpool They want messages to be purged after specific times. What you've mentioned is for a client waiting for a server response, not what OP is after.

Comment: ya i'm trying to understand this question

Answer (score 1):

Given that Kafka messages are an ordered log, it is not possible to have messages removed from the *middle* of the log. Therefore, I do not believe that what you are asking for is possible.